# Can I wait for a specific child process to terminate in perl

Tags: linux, perl, parallel-processing

Currently, I'm trying to create an orphaned process by having proc A create proc B and proc B create proc C. Then, I want to kill proc B so that proc C is no longer attached to the process tree of proc A. However, I also want to know the process id of proc C in proc A. So far as an example, I have tried:

```
use FileHandle;
pipe(READ, WRITE);

WRITE->autoflush();
my $pid1 = fork();
if ($pid1) {
  #Proc A
  waitpid($pid1, 0);
  close WRITE;
  my $msg = <READ>;
  print "msg: $msg\n";
} elsif ($pid1 == 0) {
  #Proc B
  my $pid2 = fork();
  if ($pid2) {
    #Proc B
    print WRITE $pid2;
    exit 0;
  } elsif ($pid2 == 0) {
    #Proc C
    print "child 2 proc $$\n";
    sleep(5);
    exit 0;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, running this makes proc A wait for proc C to finish (sleep 5) before it prints the id of proc C which is not what I want. Is there a way to have the waitpid function return once proc B exits?

Alternatively, is there a better way to create an orphan process?

EDIT: added info regarding read/write pipe.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your script, it doesn't behave in the way you describe.  This may be related to the mechanics of the READ and WRITE handles which you've omitted.

However *I think* the `POSIX::setsid()` function does what you want.  It puts a process into its own process group which is disconnected from the controlling TTY of the parent process:

```
use POSIX qw();


# after forking, in the child process that you want to become an orphan
    POSIX::setsid();
```

Comment: I added some info about the read/write pipe. Also, I inserted the setsid as:
POSIX::setsid(); print "child 2 proc $$\n"; But it didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like below to implement this:

```
use FileHandle;
pipe(READ, WRITE);

WRITE->autoflush();

my $cmd = "nohup ./test.sh";

my $pid1 = fork();
if ($pid1) {
  #parent
  my $kid;
  $kid = waitpid($pid1, 0);
  close WRITE;
  my $msg = <READ>;
  print "msg: $msg\n";
  sleep(10);
} elsif ($pid1 == 0) {
  #1st child
  my $pid2 = fork();
  if ($pid2) {
    #1st child
    print WRITE $pid2;
    exit 0;
  } elsif ($pid2 == 0) {
    exec $cmd;
    exit 0;
  }
}
```